# How to Change the value of the last row of a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I would like to select the last row of a datagridview and change the row value using textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the value of last row using a text box, under the text_changed event of the textbox, enter the following code:

```
Dim last As Integer = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
dataGridView1.Rows(last).Cells(0).Value = Textbox1.Text
'sets the value of the last row of the datagridview to the value of the text in the textbox
```

Comment: That is C#. The question is tagged vb.bet

Comment: @Mary Fixed it, really sorry 'bout that

Comment: Still a bit of C# syntax Dim last As Integer :-)

Comment: wow!, seems like i'm really used to c#, thanks for the corrections @Mary